# What's the difference between mdb vue and bootstrap vue?

Tags: c#, vue.js, model-view-controller, razor

I'm using bootstrap-vue.css library, vue.js, bootstrap-vue.js, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js in c#.net mvc with razor. What vue library can I use without having any conflict ? No jquery needed.

I'm currently using

```
<div>
 <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="info">
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

Instead of

```
<mdb-navbar color="indigo" dark>

</mdb-navbar>
```

Answer (score 5):

[Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_bootstrap.asp) is a "CSS Framework"

> Bootstrap makes front-end web development faster and easier. It’s made
>   for folks of all skill levels, devices of all shapes, and projects of
>   all sizes. Bootstrap ships with vanilla CSS, but its source code
>   utilizes the two most popular CSS preprocessors, Less and Sass. With
>   Bootstrap, you get extensive and beautiful documentation for common
>   HTML elements, dozens of custom HTML and CSS components, and awesome
>   jQuery plugins.

---

[Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) is a "Design Language" that was developed by Google.

> Material Design (codenamed Quantum Paper)[1](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_bootstrap.asp) is a design language that
>   Google developed in 2014. Expanding on the "card" motifs that debuted
>   in Google Now, Material Design uses more grid-based layouts,
>   responsive animations and transitions, padding, and depth effects such
>   as lighting and shadows.

---

[MDB](https://darshansaroya.com/bootstrap-vs-mdbootstrap/) just takes the "Design Practices" from Material Design, while using Bootstrap's native components.

> MDBootstrap stands for material design for bootstrap. Or in simple
>   word, a version of bootstrap that inspired with Material Designs.
>   MDBootstrap have hundreds of beautiful components, templates,
>   animations, effects and helpers. Everything fully responsive,
>   compatible with different browsers and it is easy to use.

---

So to sum it up, the main difference is that one (MDB) is following a structured design pattern. Google has a set of specifications that make up Material Design.

Comment: and what will happen if I'll use both ? Is there a conflict?

Answer (score -2):

I'm using bootstrap-vue.css library, vue.js, bootstrap-vue.js, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js in c#.net mvc with razor. What vue library can I use without having any conflict ? No jquery needed.

Comment: you should update your question, not post as answer about your details...